Can I create multiple OP_RETURN UTxO in single transaction
Is it possible to generate multiple OP_RETURN utxos in one transaction?
I see there is an answer for that in 2015, I wonder if it's still the case.
I know nothing prevents us from doing so, but question is, do miners accept these kind of transactions?

If you pay the fees there's no motivation for the miners to don't pick your transaction with multiple OP_RETURNS

@polespinasa Thanks for the response, but the previous answer says: "such a transaction would not be considered a 'standard' transaction and would not be relayed (propagated) through the network.". So, are you sure about your answer?

That means that nodes (non-miners) will not propagate the transaction because they will label it as non-standard, but it still complies with the consensus rules and is a valid transaction so if it reaches a miner and he acts on economic incentives he will take it.

Such a transaction would be valid, but considered non-standard by most nodes on the Bitcoin network. It is unlikely that such a transaction would propagate to miners and would be included by miners unless further steps would be taken beyond submitting to your own node.
Also OP_RETURN outputs are not part of the UTXO set. They are provably unspendable, so we do not track them among the Unspent Transaction Output set.

thanks for the response. Is there any document around things that make transaction non-standard? I checked devguide but there was no statement about multiple OP_RETURN making transaction non-standard. link: https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/transactions.html#non-standard-transactions
